# PgAdmin4 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I used to have a functioning PostgreSQL database, but upon reinstalling due to computer issues, I am now getting this error after launching:

````
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'```
````

Comment: I have this issue as well. never had it before. I made sure to allow these through windows firewall. You may want to specify a few things. 

1. Is pgAdmin on the same machine as your database?
2. Have you tried anything to get this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186097) reply recommends, I removed described file (C:\Users{User name}\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db on Windows), added user environment varible SQLITE_PATH = 'C:\Users{User name}\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db' and launched pgAdmin. Worked for me.